# Edit a row in grid Extjs4

Tags: grid, extjs4

I have a grid and a window with few textboxes and button.i want the values in row to appear in text box when window is opened on button click.i m able to alert a value of test function.

Comment: Your question is not clear.. Try to be more clear.

Comment: I m popullating data in grid and in evry row i have a button which opens a new window when clicked. The values in the row should popullate in the text field of window which is opened on button click.i m using rowindex and getAt() to get the values of row in the text fields.after getting the values i want to set the values and update into grid . Polpulating the new values in grid on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the selected row values you can use:

```
var records = Ext.getCmp('your_grid_id').getSelectionModel().getSelection(),
record  = records.length === 1 ? records[0] : null;
alert(record.get('a_row_title'); // specified in the model
```

To set the value to a text field:

```
Ext.getCmp('your_textField_id').setValue(record.get('...'));
```